# recover a dropped connection in socket.io

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

Ocassionally my upstream node app yields a 502 Bad Gateway in nginx, which cause the socket.io client to get dropped Im assuming, because no more events come after that point.

Is there anything I can do to reestablish the connection?